# Django on Apache 2.2.15 on centos 6.5

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, wsgi

i install django(1.11) and python 3.5 and virtualenv in my centos production server (centos 6.5)

when i start django locally using python manage.py runserver i can use the django but i can't serve my django on apache with mod WSGI
i test very difference configuration on /conf.s/django.conf but i faced with this error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5713): Target WSGI script '/var/www/path/to/site/myapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

this is my django.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIProcessGroup myapp 
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp display-name=%{GROUP}
ServerName test.com
ServerAlias www.test.com
ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
DocumentRoot    /path/to/root
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/root/myapp/wsgi.py
Alias /static /path/to/root/myapp/static
ErrorLog  /path/to/error.log
CustomLog /path/to/access.log combined </VirtualHost>
```

how can i handle this issue ?

Comment: How did you install mod-wsgi? It has to be compiled against a certain Python version. If you yum installed, I'm guessing you got a very out of date Python 2 version from yum.

Comment: Yes the wsgi was installed with yum, how can i compile wsgi for python 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be running a `yum` installed version of `mod_wsgi`, which is very out of date and compiled against Python 2.7. The easiest way to install Python 3.5 and `mod_wsgi` is by using the IUS repository, which provides up-to-date packages for RedHat and CentOS. I'm going to assume you're running 64-bit.

First, uninstall `mod_wsgi` installed from EPEL:

```
sudo yum -y remove mod_wsgi
```

This will install the IUS repository:

```
sudo yum -y install https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
```

Once installed, you can install Python 3.5 and `mod_wsgi`:

```
sudo yum -y install python35u
sudo yum -y install python35u-pip
sudo yum -y install python35u-mod_wsgi
```

This will install `mod_wsgi` at `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi_python3.5.so`, which is where you'll have to load it from in your Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi_python3.5.so
```

You will also need to ensure that your `virtualenv` points to Python 3.5 when you create it:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 myapp
```

What all of this does is ensures that the same Python version (3.5) is running your Django code through your virtualenv, and your web server (`mod_wsgi`) without affecting the system Python version (version 2.6.6 on CentOS 6). Good luck!